# What is iOS Home App URL Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iot, swift4

Does anyone know the URL Scheme for iOS Home App? I have searched anywhere on internet but none of the results resolve my issue. There was also an article on how to get URL Schemes but it only applies to none Apple built-in iOS apps. Also, I have found this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67059 but no answers in it.

Thanks!

Comment: If what you're asking is for a way for apps to bring the user to the home screen, then I don't believe that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Home App you may try with this one: `com.apple.home://`

some apple bundle identifiers here: [com.apple.*](https://github.com/joeblau/apple-bundle-identifiers)

Comment: Great! Thank you for sharing the rest of Apple identifiers.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/2450755/andrea-mugnaini I have another post about deep linking Home App, if you can share some thoughts I'd gladly take it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745031/ios-deep-linking-set-home-app-to-select-rooms-tab-when-opening Hoping to see your suggestions. Thanks!